# What is the C# equivalent of XAML's "/" in data-binding paths?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, collectionviewsource

I have 3 entities in entity framework:

collection

subcollection

subsubcollection

The collection entity has a one-to-many relationship with the subcollection entity, which in turn has a one-to-many relationship with the subsubcollection entity. All are observable collections accessed via the `CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource`.

Now, traversing down the hierarchy of collectionViewSource is easy in XAML; I can just write something like `ItemsSource="{Binding collectionViewSource/subcollection/subsubcollection}"` to traverse through the current item at each level.

In C#, I can get to the current collection item in my view by writing `collectionViewSource.View.CurrentItem`. However, I need to be able to delve deeper than this, accessing the current subcollection item to see its subsubcollection. How do I do this?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent. `/` does a property traversal, but takes in to account the binding's current position through parent / child bindings.  You would need to look at the current item of the `CollectionViewSource` of all bindings through the tree to get the current value. This is no simple task.

Comment: Ah, I had worried this might be the case. I could potentially get the subsubcollection from a ListView in the UI, but that feels like it kind of ruins my separation of concerns, and anyways I already have a reference to the collectionViewSource so it seemed like it would have been a much cleaner way to go about it.

Comment: Don't you have a reference to the collection you're working with? It seems a bit odd you're looking for the currentitem 3 levels down.Are you really binding directly to entity framework objects rather than viewmodels holding their data?

Comment: I have to agree with @Andy.  I actually had to look up what the `/` in path binding syntax did, as I had never encountered it before.  When I've done this kind of multi-level binding in the past, I've always had a property on the viewmodel for the selected item at each level.  This way, accessing the value of the 3rd layer down is as simple as examining the property's value on the viewmodel for the layer that I'm interested in.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, your first comment answered the question I guess, so we should promote it to an answer. Anyways, maybe this is just a misunderstanding on my part of best practices with the binding engine. In my program, I will have a Grid in the XAML with `DataContext = "{StaticResource collectionViewSource}"`, and then a subitem within that control (ie, a ListView) with `ItemsSource="{Binding subcollection}"`, and I just let the binding engine do its thing. I don't touch any of the bound collections in the code behind except to load data. But here I need to for some logic in an event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of `/` in C#. `/` does a property traversal, much like `.`, but takes in to account the binding's current position through parent / child bindings on other controls. You would need to look at the current item of the `CollectionViewSource` of all bindings through the tree to get the current value. If you don't have access to these controls, or the CollectionViewSources, this may not be simple.